# Pass link on button click

Tags: blazor

Depending on the number of previousLinks (AddData.previousLinks.Count), Previous links buttons are displayed. Clicking on a particular link button, should pass that particular link name to LastLinkAccessed method. But says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". May I know where I am going wromg.

- @AddData.previousLinks[i] works and displays all linknames inside div
- But have trouble passing link name to LastLinkAccessed method on button click

  ```
   <div>
      <ul>             
         @if (AddData.previousLinks.Count > 0)
         {
             @for (var i = 0; i < AddData.previousLinks.Count; i++)
             {
                      <li class="dropdown-item">
                           <button class="file" id="file0" onclick=LastLinkAccessed(@AddData.previousLinks[i])> 
                           @* @onclick="() =>LastLinkAccessed(@AddData.previousLinks[i])"  *@ 
                           </button>
                     </li>
             }
        }             
      </ul>                                
   </div>


  @code{
      public string linkname1 { get; set; }

       private async Task LastLinkAccessed(string linkname)
       {
           linkname1 = linkname;          
           await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "linkname1", linkname1);
           UriHelper.NavigateTo("/" + @linkname1);
       }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that either by introducing a local variable to your for loop, or still better, by using foreach loop.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        @if (AddData.previousLinks.Count > 0)
        {
            @for (var i = 0; i < AddData.previousLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                var local = i;
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <button class="file" id="file0" @onclick="() => LastLinkAccessed(AddData.previousLinks[local])">
                        @AddData.previousLinks[local]
                    </button>
                </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>


@code{
    public string linkname1 { get; set; }

     private async Task LastLinkAccessed(string linkname)
     {
         linkname1 = linkname;
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", 
                                     "linkname1", linkname1);
         UriHelper.NavigateTo("/" + @linkname1);
     }
}
```